# Set environment variables to a Python process called from a Bash script

Tags: python, bash, cross-compiling

I have a setup.py script that obviously builds an application, the case is that this is called from a Bash script which defines some environment variables before calling the Python one.

I need to change the CC and CXX to a different compiler because I need to cross-compile, but not always, so I want these variables to be modified when needed. If I do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

python2 setup.py build
```

The setup.py doesn't preserve the value of these variables. Is there a way to do that?

PD: I don't have the --compiler option that I found in some other posts.

Comment: What you have written is correct. The code is obviously not looking at the environment.

Comment: Well, if you type the following inside the setup.py:

**os.environ["CC"] ='arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'
os.environ["CXX"] ='arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++'**

Then it works, that's why I thought what I've written don't works.

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings? If so, both values end with a carriage return, which would explain the difference between your shell script and setting the variables inside `setup.py`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean with DOS line endings?

Comment: The convention in DOS (and continued in Windows) is for each line to be terminated by a carriage-return/line-feed (CR/LF) pair, while `bash` expects a line to be terminated according to the UNIX convention of a single line-feed character. As such, `bash` would interpret the CR from a CR/LF pair as an ordinary character. If this is the problem, you need to change the file from DOS to UNIX format. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info (scroll down to "Before asking about problematic code".)

Comment: The only reason I can think of for this not working is if something that your 'setup.py' uses tries to be "clever" and resets them.